# highcharts export differs from presented one

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have the following charts rendered:

A:
[image: chart A]

B:
[image: chart B legend]

but when I get export, there are some problems, for example in chart A:

[image: chart A problems] ==> the title is messy and yAxis title is absolutely exploded! (I send chart.options to my export server, so I expoect exported image be the same as what I see)

[image: chart B problems] ==> legend is ruined

Then if I add this code:

```
exporting: {
    allowHTML: true
},
```

all problems are fixed, but new problems emerge, there is no rotation at all!

chart A: [image: chart A new problems] ==> as you can see both yAxis title and xAsis labels are not rotated anymore, and even if I add rotation to them they do not rotate:

```
exporting: {
    allowHTML: true,
    chartOptions: {
        yAxis:{
            title:{
                rotation: 90
            }
        }
    }
},
```

chart B: 
[image: chart B new problems] ==> parentheses are messed and there is overlap between texts and symbols.

my code:

```
yAxis: {
    title: {
        margin: 20,
        useHTML: true,
        style: {
            color: '#6B6D6E',
            fontSize: '14px'
        }
    },
    labels: {
        useHTML: true,
        style: {
            color: '#888888'
        }
    },
    gridLinesWidth: 1,
    plotLines: [{
        value: 0,
        width: 1,
        dashStyle: "Dash",
        color: "#acacac",
        zIndex: 4
    }]
},
```

my legend code:

```
legend:{
        useHTML: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        layout: "horizontal",
        align: "center",
        verticalAlign: "bottom",
        alignColumns: true,
        rtl: true,
        itemWidth: null,
        width: null,
        x: 20
    }
```

is there any way to fix these problems?

---

*update 1:*

```
exporting: {
    chartOptions: {
        legend:{
            symbolPadding: 20,
            rtl: true,
            reversed: true
        }
    }
},
```

and the result is: [image: after update 1]

symbols are not stuck to right border (it seems like a bug, with *rtl: false* padding is only applied to right of symbol only, but in *rtl: right* padding is applied to both sides of symbol)

Comment: Could you provide a live demo (on jsfiddle ideally) that recreates this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
legend:{ symbolPadding: -20 ,rtl:true,reversed:true}
```

Comment: it somehow bettered the situation but still not the best, check my update.